# Identify code creating socket in java for socket going to CLOSE_WAIT state

Tags: java, class, sockets, port

I am getting lot of CLOSE_WAIT sockets and not able to determine which file/ line is responsible for the socket in CLOSE_WAIT state.
I am able to determine the port number which is going to CLOSE_WAIT and the process associated with the port number using lsof -Pni : | more and ss commands. But Unable to figure out the java class where the port is created.
Is there a way to identify the java class which is responsible for creating the socket which is going to close wait state.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You can start your application in debug mode and if the program have   CLOSE_WAIT states than try to pause your program and look into the stacktrace.
Or:
 Perhaps you can use VisualVM to analyse with classes , objects and threads are in the JVM. 
https://visualvm.java.net/

But I think there is no direct way to see witch port is bind to witch class.